# Maximum speed in pipeline modelling in vhdl

Tags: vhdl

I have 2 blocks with a speed of 150MHz and 234.56 MHz. I would like to connect them using structural modelling. How to achieve at least 150 MHz?

Answer (score 0):

Just connect them up and use the 150MHz clock to clock them both.  Just because one block *can* run at 234.56MHz, doesn't (usually) mean it *has* to.

Answer (score 0):

If the blocks have pipeline registers on input and output, they should interconnect and work at the speed of the slower one. Just clock both blocks off the 150MHz clock.

If they do not, you may need to interconnect them via pipeline registers in your structural design. Just add one clocked process to implement all the pipeline registers.